# Windows10の環境で docker コマンドを実行するとエラーが発生する

Tags: windows, docker

Docker を Docker Desktop Installer を使ってインストールしました。
その後コンテナを起動しようとして Windows PowerShell で下記のコマンドを実行するとエラーが発生する。
処置方法について教えていただけませんか？

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run hello-world
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Comment: (1) Docker はどのようにインストールされましたか？　(2) これまで Docker は動作していましたか？　それともこれが最初の起動ですか？

Comment: (1)Dockerのインストールは、Docker Desktop Installer を使いインストールしました。(2)最初の起動です。お手数をお掛けしますが、ご教示願います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらく Docker Desktop が起動していません。

スタートメニューから「Docker Desktop」を探し、起動してください。

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

> Docker Desktop does not start automatically after installation. To start Docker Desktop, search for Docker, and select Docker Desktop in the search results.
>
> [image]
>
> When the whale icon in the status bar stays steady, Docker Desktop is up-and-running, and is accessible from any terminal window.
>
> [image]
>   If the whale icon is hidden in the Notifications area, click the up arrow on the taskbar to show it. To learn more, see Docker Settings.
>
> After installing the Docker Desktop app, you also get a pop-up success message with suggested next steps, and a link to this documentation.
>
> [image]

Comment: ご指摘の通り、dockerを走らせたら正常に動作しました。ありがとうございました。